# can xquery be run practically from the CLI?

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery, saxon, basex

How is [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/HelloWorld) sample `xquery` executed [from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44395516/262852) the CLI?

```
xquery version "1.0";
let $message := 'Hello World!'
return
<results>
   <message>{$message}</message>
</results>
```

[image: xquery]

Inspired from zx485's answer:

> Check the separate libxslt page
>
> XSL Transformations, is a language for transforming XML documents into
>   other XML documents (or HTML/textual output).
>
> A separate library called libxslt is available implementing XSLT-1.0
>   for libxml2. This module "libxslt" too can be found in the Gnome SVN
>   base.
>
> You can check the progresses on the libxslt Changelog.
>
> Daniel Veillard

http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT.html

Comment: `basex hello.xq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with Saxon like in [this extensive tutorial](http://etutorials.org/XML/xml+hacks/Chapter+2.+Creating+XML+Documents/Hack+24+Execute+an+XQuery+with+Saxon/).

To summarize it, copy the XQuery code to a file (here named `test.xq`) and then execute it with (the current version of) Saxon:

```
java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query test.xq
```

The output in your sample case would be

```
<results>
    <message>Hello World!</message>
</results>
```

as desired.

Comment: as a practical matter, do many people run .xq from the CLI?  chain them together?  or, is that madness?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. But to me, it doesn't seem that unusual. I would just weight its use cases against applying an XSLT-3.0 file. What's better? (Probably) you decide it for yourself.

Comment: If you're running multiple queries, then you don't want the overhead of loading the Java VM for each one; if you're running a pipeline then you probably want something like XProc or Ant or xmlsh to link things together. But plenty of people want convenience above performance, and for that, running from a shell is just fine.